# MongoDB SocketException in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mongodb, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to use Robo 3T 1.3 to connect to a remote mongodb server with ssh proxy. The remote server and the proxy box are in AWS.

I am given the following error:

[image: MongoDB error]

Not sure if I am missing some settings or why this is happening.
Security groups are set up in a way that TCP connection is allowed from the proxy with 22 and 27017 ports to the Mongodb instance.

Sometimes it works, but most cases it doesn't. Not sure why it wants to use the 57013 port, my guess is that the mongod socket listening on port 27017 and it opens a new one for the communication.

Any idea what I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: How did you set up the ssh tunnel? Is it actually active?

Comment: It is an AWS ec2 instance having a public IP. Yes, it is active. Robo can connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue I had was local, nothing was wrong in AWS. For some reason Robo 3T had issues with the local port for the ssh...